# continuous projections to finite dimensional subspaces of normed spaces

Tags: normed-spaces

If $X$ is a normed space and $Y$ is a finite dimensional subspace, then there exists a continuous linear projection $P$ from $X$ to $Y$.
Our teacher gave us the instruction to use the following fact:
Let $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ in $X$ be linearly independent. Then there exist $x'_1,\cdots,x'_n$ in $X'$ such that $x'_k(x_r)= \delta_{kr}, 1 \le k,r \le n$.
How does one proceed with this assumption?
Thank you!

Comment: Let $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ a basis for $Y$, and define $P:X\to Y$, $P=x_1x'_1+\cdots+x_nx'_n$

Comment: Hello Yuki, please do help me with how one is supposed to use the property to solve the question. Why is it possible to define the mapping P like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Yuki gave you the answer.

Define $P:X\to X$ by $Px = \sum x_k'(x) x_k$. Show that $P$ is linear, continuous and $P P = P$.

Comment: How does one show that P is continuous? And where is the property mentioned in the question used in the construction of P?

Comment: I mean, if x'k(x) equals delta k, so how does that help?

Comment: Also, if we try to show that PP is P, we consider Px = sum x'k(x)xk. This is sum of delta k.xk. Here, both quantities depend on k, so when we want to apply P again on this expression, which term is the new "x"?

Comment: This is homework. You need to do some work. Showing continuity is almost trivial using the triangle inequality. Linearity is trivial. Use the 'orthogonality' property to show $P^2=P$. You have a definition for $P$. Replace the '$x$' by $Px$. Expand the inner sum using a different letter for the inner summation.

Comment: Yes, I showed the linearity and continuity. I am getting stuck at a particular part in the proof of the projection. There are two ways to proceed to show P square is P. The first is the way I did in the prev post. Following your suggestion when I start with P(P(x)) and write this as sum of x'k(Px)xk, then this automatically becomes equal to sum of delta k. xk. Where is the need for the inner summation, then?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, does the proof go this way: P(Px)) = sum(x'k(Px)xk) = sum(x'k(sum(x'j(x).xj)xk) = sum(xj x'k(sum(x'j(x))xk). Now applying that xj.xk=0 if j not equals k, I don't understand the result.

Comment: $P(Px) = \sum_k x_k^'(Px) x_k = \sum_k x_k^'(\sum_j x_j^'(x) x_j) x_k = \sum_k \sum_j x_j^'(x) x_k^'(  x_j) x_k = \sum_k x_k^'(x) x_k = Px$